# Finding records with certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called `Nodes` and there is a `node_type` field there. I have a model called `Node`. It's basic model and there's a model called `Page`. `Page` extended from `Node`. I want that `Page.all` returned all rows with `'node_type' = 'page'`. Also I want `count` method an others worked same way. Is there any way to do it? Maybe I should replace or set addition condition before calling find/all of parent class. How can I do it? Maybe there is another way?

Comment: ... First, if you're using something like STI, this should work out-of-the-box. Second, look up scopes.

Comment: find more informations adding and requesting on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: If you update the question with the schema of your models, that will help us help you more easily. That being said, without knowing your schema, have you tried things like `Page.where("node_type = ?", page)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Page class can you have a default_scope.

```
default_scope where(node_type: 'page')
```